# How to access a label from outside of the MainWindow class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a label `label1` that I'm trying to update the contents of from a separate class `Server()`.

I have tried linking the MainWindow() instance to my Server() class via:

```
//MainWindow constrcutor
Server.GetMainWindow(this);


//Server()
public static MainWindow mainWindow;

GetMainWindow(MainWindow mw)
{
       mainWindow = mw
}
```

This allows me to see the property `mainWindow.Label.Content`, but I don't "see" the change when I run my code.

I also tried going about this the other way.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Server.mainWindow = this;
}
```

But still the same result.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access the already opened instance of your MainWindow is to use the Application.Current.Windows collection:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>();
if (mainWindow != null)
   mainWindow.Label.Content = "...";
```

This should update the Content property of the Label with an x:Name of "Label" that is declared in the XAML markup of the MainWindow.